# Just opt-in Windows Insider fast ring but it is not finding updates?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-insider

I just enable Insider Preview Build under Windows Update > Advanced options > Get Insider Preview, then I moved the slider to the Fast level. After that I restarted my computer. I also have Developer mode activated and my Windows is in en-US.

But it doesn't seem to be installing anything related to insider builds.

My registry looks like this:

[image: registry]

I tried running

```
%windir%\system32\wuauclt.exe /detectnow
```

But nothing happened.

What else do I have to do to get the updates?

Comment: Download the current Insider Preview .ISO, mount the image, and install it manually.  There are a bunch of conditions that must be trust for you to start to, move into the Insider Preview branch, from the stable branch.  It is far easier just to force it.

Comment: Out of interest since you mention "developer mode" what build are you on precisely?

Comment: @Ramhound `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>Software>Microsoft>Windows NT>CurrentVersion > CurrentBuild` says `10586`

Comment: I've just installed Insider Hub and it says I'm on `th2_release_sec 10586 Professional`

Comment: Like I said, just use the .ISO, and move directly to the build you want to use.

Comment: @Ramhound, is it possible to use the ISO and update the OS while keeping the old files and applications? Booting from the ISO, when I tried to choose that option, it says I should start Windows normally and use setup.exe. Doing that, it asks for product keys. How did you use the ISO?

Comment: Whenever I used this method, to upgrade my Windows 10 virtual machines,  I just skipped entering a product key.  I honestly had no problems which is the reason I thought nothing of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update took 3 days to show up.

Not sure if it is a wait time or a scheduled day that they broadcast the update or something.

Comment: It is weird that this is not documented anywhere.

Comment: This might nail the mystery: when did you first install Windows 10 and approx what is the time in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsSelfHost\Timestamps\EnablePreviewBuildsTimestamp ?